# Admob Ad Overlapping SurfaceView

Tags: android, admob, surfaceview, overlap

I have used the following in android manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    />
<com.Joey_Ant.Lite.GameView
    android:id="@+id/gameScreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, the ad still overlaps the surfaceview (com.Joey_Ant.Lite.GameView).

How do I make the screen adjust when the ad loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this it wont overlap surfaceview but it will leave the ad space even if ad doesnt load

```
   <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<com.Joey_Ant.Lite.GameView
    android:id="@+id/gameScreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```